# WP7. Is there any ability to set custom IP address for a host? (like file HOSTS in Windows)

Tags: windows-phone-7, dns

I'm testing my WP7 client app, that connects to my WFC service... The connection is using transport security (using SSL cert). For my device to connect to the service, I need a BaseAddress.Host to be equal to the certificate's "CN=hostname" property... So I need to resolve my HOSTNAME (myservice.com) to my computer's local ip address (192.168.1.1).
Is there any ability to add custom DNS-resolve entry to somewhere to get needed result?!
Or, maybe, there is another way to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance,
Timin Anton.

Answer (score 1):

Is this just for debugging?

If so, the only thing I can think of is to set this in your PC's HOSTS file - you can then connect from the phone using USB (just make sure that you turn off wifi and cellular data in the phone)

Would be interested to know if this works

Comment: Alternatively, if this is just for debugging then just change your WCF service to HTTP for now?